# Membership proofs for AVL trees

Tags: membership, avl-tree, proof, agda

I'm struggling a little to come up with a notion of membership proof for `Data.AVL` trees. I would like to be able to pass around a value of type `n ∈ m`, to mean that n appears as a key in in the AVL tree, so that given such a proof, `get n m` can always successfully yield a value associated with n. You can assume my AVL trees always contain values drawn from a join semilattice (A, ∨, ⊥) over a setoid (A, ≈), although below the idempotence is left implicit.

```
module Temp where

open import Algebra.FunctionProperties
open import Algebra.Structures renaming (IsCommutativeMonoid to IsCM)
open import Data.AVL
open import Data.List
open import Data.Nat hiding (_⊔_)
import Data.Nat.Properties as ℕ-Prop
open import Data.Product hiding (_-×-_)
open import Function
open import Level
open import Relation.Binary renaming (IsEquivalence to IsEq)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

module ℕ-AVL {v} (V : Set v)
  = Data.AVL (const V) (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder ℕ-Prop.strictTotalOrder)

data ≈-List {a ℓ : Level} {A : Set a} (_≈_ : Rel A ℓ) : Rel (List A) (a ⊔ ℓ) where
   [] : ≈-List _≈_ [] []
   _∷_ : {x y : A} {xs ys : List A} → (x≈y : x ≈ y) → (xs≈ys : ≈-List _≈_ xs ys) → ≈-List _≈_ (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys)

_-×-_ : {a b c d ℓ₁ ℓ₂ : Level} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {C : Set c} {D : Set d} →
          REL A C ℓ₁ → REL B D ℓ₂ → A × B → C × D → Set (ℓ₁ ⊔ ℓ₂)
(R -×- S) (a , b) (c , d) = R a c × S b d

-- Two AVL trees are equal iff they have equal toList images.
≈-AVL : {a ℓ : Level} {A : Set a} → Rel A ℓ → Rel (ℕ-AVL.Tree A) (a ⊔ ℓ)
≈-AVL _≈_ = ≈-List ( _≡_ -×- _≈_ ) on (ℕ-AVL.toList _)

_∈_ : {a ℓ : Level} {A : Set a} {_≈_ : Rel A ℓ} {_∨_ : Op₂ A} {⊥ : A}
      {{_ : IsCM _≈_ _∨_ ⊥}} → ℕ → ℕ-AVL.Tree A → Set (a ⊔ ℓ)
n ∈ m = {!!}

get : {a ℓ : Level} {A : Set a} {_≈_ : Rel A ℓ} {_∨_ : Op₂ A} {⊥ : A} →
      {{_ : IsCM _≈_ _∨_ ⊥}} → (n : ℕ) → (m : ℕ-AVL.Tree A) → n ∈ m → A
get n m n∈m = {!!}
```

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm finding it hard. One option would be to use my notion of equivalence for AVL-trees, which says that two trees are equal iff they have the same `toList` image, and exploit the commutative monoid over A, defining

n ∈ m = ≈-AVL *≈* m (ℕ-AVL.unionWith _ *∨* m (ℕ-AVL.singleton _ n ⊥))

This essentially says that m contains n iff the singleton map (n, ⊥) is "below" m in the partial order induced by the commutative monoid (technically we need the idempotence for this interpretation to make sense). However given such a definition I'm not at all sure how to implement `get`.

I have also experimented with defining my own inductive ∈ relation but found that hard as I seemed to end up having to know about the complicated internal indices used by `Data.AVL`.

Finally I also tried using a value of type `n ∈? m ≡ true`, where *∈?* is defined in `Data.AVL`, but didn't have much success there either. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to define `_∈_` as an inductive relation. Yes, this requires you to know the internals of `Data.AVL`, but I'm fairly sure this will be the most pleasant representation to work with.

The internal structure of `Data.AVL` is actually quite simple. We have a type `Indexed.Tree`, which is indexed by three values: the lower bound, the upper bound and the height. Given a tree `t : Indexed.Tree lb ub h`, all values inside `t` are within the range `(lb, ub)`.

There's a slight twist to it, though: since we need to have a tree that can contain arbitrary values, we need to artifically extend the `_<_` relation given by `isStrictTotalOrder` with two new values - you can think of those as a negative and a positive infinity. In the `Data.AVL` module, these are called `⊥⁺` and `⊤⁺`. Trees that can contain arbitrary values are then of type `Tree ⊥⁺ ⊤⁺ h`.

The last piece is the balancing: each node requires heights of its subtrees to be at most one level apart. We don't actually need to touch balancing, but the function signatures might mention it.

Anyways, I'm working directly with this raw (indexed) variant. The opaque, unindexed version is just something like:

```
data Tree : Set ? where
  tree : ∀ {h} → Indexed.Tree ⊥⁺ ⊤⁺ h
```

---

Some boilerplate first:

```
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Product
open import Level
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P using (_≡_)
open import Relation.Nullary

import Data.AVL

module Membership
  {k v ℓ}
  {Key : Set k} (Value : Key → Set v)
  {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
  (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_) where

open Data.AVL Value isStrictTotalOrder public
open Extended-key                      public
open Height-invariants                 public

open IsStrictTotalOrder isStrictTotalOrder
```

Here's the `_∈_` as an inductive relation:

```
data _∈_ {lb ub} (K : Key) :
    ∀ {n} → Indexed.Tree lb ub n → Set (k ⊔ v ⊔ ℓ) where
  here : ∀ {hˡ hʳ} V
    {l : Indexed.Tree lb [ K ] hˡ}
    {r : Indexed.Tree [ K ] ub hʳ}
    {b : hˡ ∼ hʳ} →
    K ∈ Indexed.node (K , V) l r b
  left : ∀ {hˡ hʳ K′} {V : Value K′}
    {l : Indexed.Tree lb [ K′ ] hˡ}
    {r : Indexed.Tree [ K′ ] ub hʳ}
    {b : hˡ ∼ hʳ} →
    K < K′ →
    K ∈ l →
    K ∈ Indexed.node (K′ , V) l r b
  right : ∀ {hˡ hʳ K′} {V : Value K′}
    {l : Indexed.Tree lb [ K′ ] hˡ}
    {r : Indexed.Tree [ K′ ] ub hʳ}
    {b : hˡ ∼ hʳ} →
    K′ < K →
    K ∈ r →
    K ∈ Indexed.node (K′ , V) l r b
```

This is the sort of inductive definition you'd expect: either the key is in this inner node or it's down in one of the subtrees. We could also do without the less-than, greater-than proofs, but this is more convenient - when you want to show that a tree does *not* contain a particular element, you only have to track the path `lookup` would take, instead of searching the whole tree.

How to interpret those `l` and `r` implicit arguments? Notice that is makes perfect sense: we have a key `K` and naturally we require that the values contained in `l` fall between `lb` and `K` (it's actually `[ K ]`, since we are using the extended `_<_`) and the values in `r` fall between `K` and `ub`. The balancing (`b : hˡ ∼ hʳ`) is there just so we can construct an actual tree node.

Your `get` function is then very simple:

```
get : ∀ {h lb ub n} {m : Indexed.Tree lb ub h} → n ∈ m → Value n
get (here    V) = V
get (left  _ p) = get p
get (right _ p) = get p
```

---

Well, I told you that this representation is fairly convenient to work it and I'm going to prove it. One of the properties we'd like `_∈_` to have is decidability: that is, we can construct a program that tells us whether an element is in a tree or not:

```
find : ∀ {h lb ub} n (m : Indexed.Tree lb ub h) → Dec (n ∈ m)
```

`find` will return either `yes p`, where `p` is a proof that `n` is inside `m` (`n ∈ m`), or `no ¬p`, where `¬p` is refutation of `n ∈ m`, `n ∈ m → ⊥`. We'll need one lemma:

```
lem : ∀ {lb ub hˡ hʳ K′ n} {V : Value K′}
  {l : Indexed.Tree lb [ K′ ] hˡ}
  {r : Indexed.Tree [ K′ ] ub hʳ}
  {b : hˡ ∼ hʳ} →
  n ∈ Indexed.node (K′ , V) l r b →
  (n ≯ K′ → n ≢ K′ → n ∈ l) × (n ≮ K′ → n ≢ K′ → n ∈ r)
lem (here    V) =
  (λ _ eq → ⊥-elim (eq P.refl)) , (λ _ eq → ⊥-elim (eq P.refl))
lem (left  x p) = (λ _ _ → p) , (λ ≮ _ → ⊥-elim (≮ x))
lem (right x p) = (λ ≯ _ → ⊥-elim (≯ x)) , (λ _ _ → p)
```

This tells us that if we know `n` is contained in `t` and we know `n` is less than the key of the root of `t`, then `n` must be in the left subtree (and similarly for right subtree).

Here's the implementation of `find` function:

```
find : ∀ {h lb ub} n (m : Indexed.Tree lb ub h) → Dec (n ∈ m)
find n (Indexed.leaf _) = no λ ()
find n (Indexed.node (k , v) l r _) with compare n k
find n (Indexed.node (k , v) l r _) | tri< a ¬b ¬c with find n l
... | yes p = yes (left a p)
... | no ¬p = no λ ¬∈l → ¬p (proj₁ (lem ¬∈l) ¬c ¬b)
find n (Indexed.node (k , v) l r _) | tri≈ ¬a b ¬c
  rewrite (P.sym b) = yes (here v)
find n (Indexed.node (k , v) l r _) | tri> ¬a ¬b c with find n r
... | yes p = yes (right c p)
... | no ¬p = no λ ¬∈r → ¬p (proj₂ (lem ¬∈r) ¬a ¬b)
```

The implementation is fairly straightforward, but I would suggest loading it up in Emacs, trying to replace some of the right-hand-sides with holes and see what the types are. And finally, here are some tests:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties

open Membership
  (λ _ → ℕ)
  (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)

un-tree : Tree → ∃ λ h → Indexed.Tree ⊥⁺ ⊤⁺ h
un-tree (tree t) = , t

test : Indexed.Tree _ _ _
test = proj₂ (un-tree
  (insert 5 55 (insert 7 77 (insert 4 44 empty))))

Extract : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} → Dec P → Set _
Extract {P = P} (yes _) = P
Extract {P = P} (no  _) = ¬ P

extract : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} (d : Dec P) → Extract d
extract (yes p) = p
extract (no ¬p) = ¬p

∈-test₁ : ¬ (2 ∈ test)
∈-test₁ = extract (find 2 test)

∈-test₂ : 4 ∈ test
∈-test₂ = extract (find 4 test)
```

Comment: I might have skipped over some parts of the code, so here's the full version: https://gist.github.com/vituscze/8394501

Comment: Yup, took me a while to spot that you were defining ≮ and ≢ yourself. Great explanation; I decided to read your
answer carefully, then read the code for `Data.AVL`, and finally
reconstruct your solution myself, to make sure I properly understand it. I'm almost done with it. You're right, the internals of `Data.AVL` are not as scary as they first look!

Comment: Ok, that was a great exercise. I seemed to need a couple of `{bal = bal}` compared to your code, but otherwise I didn't have any problems.  had to cheat for the `rewrite (P.sym b)` step - I was trying `rewrite P.refl` and the error message was undecipherable. Am I right in thinking I can't put proper patterns (i.e. with constructors), but only pattern variables, in `with` patterns? (Maybe something to do with the way `with` desugars?)

Comment: @Roly: Well, `rewrite P.refl` does precisely nothing: given `P.refl : x ≡ x`, it replaces every `x` with `x`. The error message was probably because Agda couldn't tell what's the type of `P.refl`. Is it `1 ≡ 1`? `42 ≡ 42`? Or perhaps `Tree ≡ Tree`? You get the idea. You can certainly do `with` on constructor, it's just not very useful.

Comment: This is the message that made me think constructor names weren't allowed in `with` patterns: `The pattern variable refl has the same name as the constructor _≡_.refl`.